# get more than one return from SharePoint peoplepicker to store in list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

I keep getting a message of "You can only enter one name." in the peoplepicker input box(div)  I created with the following code:

```
// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    // Render and initialize the picker. 
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}
```

Even though it has the "schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;" declaration, in the div that I have to place the user input peoplepicker in, I still get the only one name allowed message.  Why?

It lets me enter more than one name and select the name from the dropdown that pops up, but appears not to let me gather all the names from the input box, when I go to collect the names.

Comment: I'm still coming up with nothing, except something about it, where <FIELD> in XML, needing MULT = TRUE;  and I don't think that applies to me.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo of:

schema['AllowMulitpleValues'] = true;

not:

schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;

I couldn't copy my existing code here from my source.  I had to type it in directly, and didn't catch the difference, until a coworker caught it.  The 'il' to 'li' needed switch.